# on iPad, modal video doesn't show up after it's been closed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to use a video in a modal dialog. But on iPad the video doesn't show up after it's been closed once. On the video.js project on github, they have closed the issue about that. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/224 But the problem still exist in Video.js 4.3.0.

The user Dartoism on Github has created a jsfiddle about that.

```
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/catwalk/ffLNJ/1/
```

is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem yesterday and the way around is hiding/showing the videos using `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead of `display:none`/ `display:block`.